What is the personally identifiable information in the developer survey?
I started the 2024 developer survey and stopped on page 1:

On that note, throughout the survey, certain answers you and your peers give will be treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore kept out of the anonymized results file.

That's fine, but what specifically is that PII?
Reason: So that I can determine what is not considered PII.

I assumed that this statement meant that as I was logged in to my SO account when I answered the survey the answers would be separated from the login PII

I can kind of generalize that to "Can we for once not do minimal effort and actually not be ambiguous?" - and I fully support that notion. Statements like what is quoted are just terrible communication methods, an F for effort.
